# Webpack can not resolve module

Tags: npm, webpack, yarnpkg, vscode-extensions, rollupjs

I need some guidance. I am experiencing an issue where webpack throws an error that it can not find a module . I was trying to add a require statement of a package(included as dependency). I got it working in another project where I don't need webpack. The code looks basically as follows:

```js
context.subscriptions.push(
vscode.commands.registerCommand("vstodo.helloWorld", () => {
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage(
        "test"
    );
    const sfdx = require('sfdx-node');
    sfdx.auth.web.login({
        setdefaultdevhubusername: true,
        setalias: 'HubOrg'
    })
        .then(() => {
            // Display confirmation of source push
            console.log('Source pushed to scratch org');
        });

}));
```

My webpack config can be found [here](https://github.com/RubenHalman/test/blob/dev/build/node-extension.webpack.config.js)
I uploaded a simplified version of the repository here [Repository](https://github.com/RubenHalman/test)
containing all the configuration files for rollup and webpack.
If I leave out the part starting at the require statement everything works again.

Any help on how to tackle this would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The vscode extension page has a short troubleshooting guide about this: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension#webpack-critical-dependencies.

They suggest the following solutions:

> - Try to make the dependency static so that it can be bundled.
> - Exclude that dependency via the `externals` configuration. Also make sure that those JavaScript files aren't excluded from the packaged extension, using a negated glob pattern in `.vscodeignore`, for example `!node_modules/mySpecialModule`.